how to directly open a base64 svg in browser with hyperlink
i got a base64 svg img and link in html, like:
<a href="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0..." target="_blank">img</a>

but when i click the img link, a new window (looks like blank) flash and disappear very quickly and nothing more.
if add the 'download' attribute, like:
<a href="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0..." target="_blank" download>img</a>

the svg img could be download successfully and open in browser.
if directly paste the data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0... into the browser url bar, the svg could be open directly as expected.
how should i use the <a> tag correctly to open the base64 svg directly in browser?
thanks very much.


use iframe or embed tag
you can us js to open it in new tab as follows:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>SVG Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="openSVG()">img</a>

    <script>
    function openSVG() {
        // Your Base64 encoded SVG data
        const svgData = atob("PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwIiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMTAwIDEwMCI+CiAgPGNpcmNsZSBjeD0iNTAiIGN5PSI1MCIgcj0iNDQiIHN0eWxlPSJmaWxsOnJlZDsiIC8+Cjwvc3ZnPg==");

        // Create a Blob from the SVG data
        const blob = new Blob([svgData], { type: 'image/svg+xml' });
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

        // Open the Blob URL in a new window
        window.open(url, '_blank'); // No 'noopener,noreferrer' here
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>



when you click img


thanks very much for advice, i tried and however, it looks like the new open tab is related to the origin one...if i zoom the new tab and the original zoom together...is there a way to cut this related thing? thanks

im a noob to html and thanks again for this sample code :), i wish the new tab is just behavior like i paste the url in address bar and enter in browser.

did it help or not just let me know , and please explain me clear so that i can help you debug i did not get your first comment.

the js method works, as a new window opened with the svg img, just a little problem as said, the related thing makes the new tab and original one zoom togather...

ok i have updated the code for you using blob if that staisfies your answer

works great and as expected, thanks so much
